# Undefined key coming

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the code:

```
var xx=[];
xx['1'] ={'a':'bb','c':'dd'}
debugger;
document.log(xx);
```

When I print xx it says undefined for key

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/kjuhpgn2/

Can you let me know why "undefined" is coming instead of "1" as key?

Edit:

I got that, it should be  {} instead of []

var xx={};

Answer (score 1):

Array indexing start at `0`.

What it's saying is that you have nothing at index `0`.

When you set `xx[1]=something` starting from an array of size `0`, you set the length of the array to `2`, with your something at index 1 and with `undefined` "filling" the position at index 0.

If what you want is to store a dictionary, then don't use an array but an object as map:

```
var xx={};
xx['1'] ={'a':'bb','c':'dd'}
```

[image]

This way you wouldn't create a sparse array.